# Changing conventions with FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

Where is the appropriate place to override the default migration conventions in FluentMigrator? Should it be done with the runner, or inside a migration? Or elsewhere?

Specifically, I would like to change the index naming convention to match that used by ServiceStack (e.g. `IX_Foo_Bar` => `uidx_foo_bar`).

I see the method `MigrationBase.ApplyConventions(IMigrationContext )` where `IMigrationContext` has an `IMigrationConventions` property... Should I create my own `MigrationContext` inside the migration? What if I want all migrations to use the same conventions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only way I found to change the conventions. You need to create an abstract class that extends "FluentMigrator.Migration" changing its conventions. Then, all your migration class should extend this class instead of FluentMigrator.Migration.

```cs
public abstract class BaseMigration : Migration
{
    // Update conventions for up migration
    public override void GetUpExpressions(IMigrationContext context)
    {
        this.UpdateConventions(context);
        base.GetUpExpressions(context);
    }

    // Update conventions for down migration
    public override void GetDownExpressions(IMigrationContext context)
    {
        this.UpdateConventions(context);
        base.GetDownExpressions(context);
    }

    // Change the conventions
    public void UpdateConventions(IMigrationContext context)
    {
        var conventions = ((MigrationConventions)context.Conventions);
        conventions.GetIndexName = index => DefaultMigrationConventions.GetIndexName(index).Replace("IX_", "uidx_");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. We already have a custom base class for our versioning scheme so this is not bad.